# Asp.net / IIS authentication for static content (for example images) best practices

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

I need to make a website with authentication of static content (images, html files, etc.)

I've already build a private section protected with a login form against a users database; but if a user knows the url of a static file of that section, it will be served anyway, logged in or not.

What are the best practices for protecting static content in asp.net?

I've found this article from [4 guys from rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135904/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122408-1.aspx), it is suitable (it works only in IIS 7.0)?

Best practices for IIS 6.0?

---

EDIT:
if i put

```
  <location path="ImagesPrivate">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

this works well, but only for .aspx files, not images or other static contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use forms auth to protect non-.net content (such as static content) on IIS6 you have 2 choices.

One is but the content in a non-browsable location & build a handler to get the content. The other option is to use wildcard mapping.

You should probably test both approaches to see which best fits your use cases.

Comment: How would be the wildcard mapping?

Answer (score 0):

please see this link
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true

" By default, IIS handles all static content itself, only invoking the ASP.NET runtime when an ASP.NET resource is requested. So we need to map those static file extensions to be handled by   ASP.NET run-time"